# In each occurrence get the total value of the height of each children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this simple html and now i am playing with jquery, but for sure i had jumped some concepts and don't know how to make my code better.

```
<div>
   <ul id="scroll1" class="scrollx">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="scroll2" class="scrollx">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="scroll3" class="scrollx">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to call the `class="scrollx"` via jquery and in each occurrence get the total value of the height of each children and store in the respective id (or array(?)). That is what i have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var totalHeight = 0;
  var scrollme = $("#scroll1");
  scrollme.before("<span class='icon-arrow-up'></span>");
  scrollme.after("<span class='icon-arrow-down'></span>");
  scrollme.children().each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
  });
  if (totalHeight <= scrollme.height()) {
   $(scrollme).siblings('span').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

As you can see i need to repeat this code three times for each `id` to archive what i want. It is so primitive this way and i really want to optimize this code, but i have no idea where to start so i am here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use jquery [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and save each `li` element height in an array:

```js
var hei = $("div ul li").map(function() {
  return $(this).height();
});

console.log(hei);
```

```css
div ul li {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="scroll1" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="scroll2" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="scroll3" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to sum the height you can use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like:

```js
var sumHeight = 0;
var hei = $("div ul li").each(function() {
  return sumHeight += ~~$(this).height();
});

console.log(sumHeight);
```

```css
div ul li {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="scroll1" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="scroll2" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="scroll3" class="scrollx">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```